# .NET Core System.Diagnostics.Activity cannot handle multiple ParentIds from traceparent header?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nginx, trace, open-telemetry

We are implementing OpenTelemetry tracing in Nginx and .NET Core microservices. We have created a local setup for Nginx according to https://opentelemetry.io/blog/2022/instrument-nginx/. This works great, multiple spans are created (one per module called in Nginx):

[Nginx spans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK4PC.png)

However these spans are all passed to the microservice via the `traceparent` header:

[Activity parent ids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EymRA.png)

It seems like `System.Diagnostics.Activity` is not able to handle this, as a new `Id` is generated that is also the `RootId`.

We have tried to set the `ParentId` using the `SetParentId()` method, however this has no effect whatsoever, in fact it doesn't change the `ParentId` at all (though the decompiled code shows no reason for doing so).

To test if it could actually work, we have used reflection to "hack" the necessary private fields:

[Hacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Wtp.png)

This of course isn't the way to go, but the test shows it could and should actually work:

[Linked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqMKE.png)

We have disabled opentelemetry for nginx and used a proxy_pass_header to pass a traceparent. This also seems to work without any issues.

Any thoughts?

Cheers,

Peter